# How to order group by and get first row?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this php mysql statement

```
SELECT a.*, p.filename, m.`first name`, m.`last name`, m.`mobile number`, m.`status`, m.`email address`
FROM map a
join members m on a.members_id = m.id
join pictures p on m.pictures_id = p.id
WHERE a.active = 1
GROUP BY a.members_id
order by a.`date added` DESC
limit 1;
```

However it's not working. The map table has records, and many of them can have the same `members_id` value. I want to group them by the `members_id`, then order them by `date added`, so the most recent is on top of each group, then only get the top row (i.e. get most recent of each group).

Does anyone know whats wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: can u slam a schema and some data in sqlfiddle. u will get an answer quicker. also i try to never use a where clause in a join unless i am dealing with nullability. include that criteria in the "on" clause

Comment: Can you confirm whether you are using MySQL or MariaDB (its open source fork)?

Comment: its the mysql from www.000webhost.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select * from
(SELECT a.*, 
        p.filename, 
        m.`first name`, m.`last name`, m.`mobile number`, m.`status`, m.`email address`
 FROM map a
 join members m on a.members_id = m.id
 join pictures p on m.pictures_id = p.id
 WHERE a.active = 1
 order by a.members_id, a.`date added` DESC) sq
GROUP BY members_id;
```

Note that the fact that MySQL returns the first row when grouping is not documented and may change in future releases - so although this query should work with current versions of MySQL, it is not guaranteed to do so in future.

Comment: @ypercube: I didn't know that - do you know when (ie. in which version of MariaDB) this behaviour diverged?

Comment: I think with the optimizer improvements in 5.3 and 5.5. The optimizer understands that the internal `ORDER BY` is redundant and removes it from the plan. See: [GROUP BY trick has been optimized away](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/)

Comment: @ypercube - thanks for that information. (I went with the order by/group trick because it was what the OP was already trying to do - I guessed that performance issues were driving it. Obviously, a correlated sub-query would normally be preferable, in MySQL.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get one result per map, you have to select it in two steps - so with a subquery. The inner query gets the newest map per member and the outer query gets all the data. Be careful with the indices, otherwise it will be very slow.

I think it will be something like:

```
    SELECT a.*, p.filename, m.`first name`, m.`last name`, m.`mobile number`, m.`status`, m.`email address`
FROM map a
inner join members m on a.members_id = m.id
inner join pictures p on m.pictures_id = p.id
inner join (
    select max(a.`date added`) as maxdate from map ia where ia.members_id = m.id)
) as sub_a on sub_a.member_id = a.member_id and sub_a.maxdate = a.`date added` 
WHERE a.active = 1
```

That depends on a single maximal `date added`, otherwise you will need some more tricks.

Comment: You need `GROUP BY ia.members_id` in the subquery and not `where ia.members_id = m.id`

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a `where` clause to filter out the records you are not interested in:

```
SELECT a.*, p.filename, m.`first name`, m.`last name`, m.`mobile number`, m.`status`, m.`email address`
FROM map a
join members m on a.members_id = m.id
join pictures p on m.pictures_id = p.id
WHERE a.active = 1 and
      a.`date added` = (select max(map.`date added`)
                        from map
                        where map.members_id = a.members_id and
                              map.active = 1
                       )
GROUP BY a.members_id
order by a.`date added` DESC;
```

Comment: `select max(map.\`date added\`)`, not `select max(a.\`date added\`)`

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this in one query. Replace the from map part with a subselect

```
select max(map_id) as map_id, members_id, max(date_added) as date_added from map where active = 1 group by members_id
```

This will give you all the members with the last dates. I have assumed your map_id existing, and being auto_increment. Use this instead of the original map table, and you will not need the group by, order and limit parts at all.